# Ruby LDAP not work in rails app but work fine in console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ldap

Below specified code runs fine in ruby(console) irb but when i put this same code in my controller show "no connection to server". Can somebody guide what is wrong with it.. Thanks.

```
require "rubygems"
require "net/ldap"

ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = "host details"
ldap.port = 389
ldap.auth "company_name\\login","password"

ldap.bind
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use gem install 'net-ldap'

require 'rubygems'
require 'net-ldap'

ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = "yourhost"
ldap.port = port
ldap.auth "your_username", "your_password"
ldap.bind
```